# condionally color text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to display each word with its color with python?  We have an example of words with their colors:

```
    Mots             Poids      colors
 0  un              0.000007    #39e600
 1  bon             0.000005    #d9ffcc
 2  rapport         0.000009    #39e600
 3  qualité/prix.   0.000014    #269900
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas, it is possible to style a series for display in, for example, Jupyter notebook.

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mots': ['un', 'bon', 'rapport', 'qualité/prix.'],
                   'colors': ['#39e600', '#d9ffcc', '#39e600', '#269900']})

def map_colors(x):
    df1 = x.copy()
    df1.loc[:, 'Mots'] = 'background-color: ' + df1.loc[:, 'colors']
    df1.loc[:, 'colors'] = 'background-color: '
    return df1

res = df.style.apply(map_colors, axis=None)
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your rest. By the way, I'd like to make a horizontal display without putting it in a data frame. But I'll try based on your proposal to find a solution.
Thank you.